# Powershell contains, check with variable not working

Tags: powershell, contains

i'm trying for several hours, but don't get why this is not working...

1. loading a CSV with multiple site entries:

https://tenant.sharepoint/sites/SiteA

https://tenant.sharepoint/sites/SiteB

https://tenant.sharepoint/sites/SiteC

https://tenant.sharepoint/sites/SiteD

2. Get all SharePoint Sites
3. Check if a SharePoint site is on CSV list

The Problem is, i always get "False" as result.
What is the issue?

```
$exceptionSites = Import-Csv -Path "Document.csv"
$siteFilter = $exceptionSites.ExceptSite

$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL | select url
   foreach ($site in $sites) 
      {

          if ($siteFilter -contains $site)
              {

                  Write-Output "Site is on list"
              }
          else 
              {         
                  Write-Output "Site is not on list"
              }
    }
```

when i change if ($siteFilter -contains "https://tenant.sharepoint/sites/SiteA") it's working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `$Sites` in your code. You'll see it still has the URL property.

Try this:

```
$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL | Select-Object -ExpandProperty url
```

Or try this:

```bsh
          if ($siteFilter -contains $site.url)
```

But don't do both.

Comment: Thank You, thats it! I didn't even think that i need to filter that property.